# page break not working on image tag

Tags: html, css, pdf, webview

Im printing html from a `WebView` inside a `PDF` and I want to use a page break after each image. So i did the following:

```
img {
    page-break-before: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

but it has no effect on my images. 
I tried to use the same on divs:

```
div {
    page-break-before: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

and it worked perfectly.

Why isnt it working on images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This property applies to block elements that generate a box. It won't apply on an empty `<div>` that won't generate a box.

— [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) about page-break

You need make your image a block-level element, e.g. with `display: block;`.

See [`page-break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before), [`page-break-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) or [`page-break-inside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside)

Answer (score 2):

I can't find this in the docs but I believe page break applies only to block level elements. Thus, apply that to your image or a container.

```
img {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```